# Apache .htaccess image exists check and redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website with file directory like this

```
/index.php (home page)

/storage (file storage directory)
    /800 (800 pixel width dir)
        /800x200.png
        /800x350.png
        ....
    /200 (200 pixel width dir)
        /200x150.png
        /200x185.png
        ...
    ....

/css
    /style.css

/images
    /logo.png

/jscript
    /autoload.js
```

Now user will make a request `http://example.com/images/200x150` or `http://example.com/images/200x180`. From two URL we know that first image is existed in `/storage/200/200x150.png` but not second one.

So, I want to write `.htaccess` for this (theoretically here).

```
Rewrite Condition /storage/{width}/{widthxheight}.png existed?
Rewrite Rule {output the image}
Rewrite Failed {go to /somedir/failed.php}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `RewriteCond path/to/file -f` this is simple rule for file if exists...

Comment: I do suggest as @Marshal explains to create rule for non existence files not to depend on existence one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples, the typical URL for an image request is like this

`http://example.com/images/WidthxHeight`

where `Width` and `Height` are variables and `images` is a fixed string.

And the typical substitution URL should be like this:

`http://example.com/storage/Width/WidthxHeight.png`

Where `Width` and `Height` are the parameters passed from the incoming URL, while `storage` and `png` are fixed string.

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Make sure the request is for an image file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/images/([^x]+)x([^/]+)/?   [NC]

# Don't want loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !storage                     [NC]

# Make sure the file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    -f

# If all conditions are met, rewrite
RewriteRule .*   /storage/%1/%1x%2.png                   [L]

## Else, map to failed.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !storage                     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !failed\.php                 [NC]
RewriteRule .*   /somedir/failed.php                     [L]
```

#### UPDATE

With 2 additional rules for incoming URLs with one parameter and no parameter.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## New option 1
## Check if the request has any parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !storage                   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    -f
RewriteRule ^images/?$   /storage/200/200x200.png      [L,NC]

## New option 2
## Check if the request has only 1 parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !x                          [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !storage                    [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    -f
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/?$   /storage/$1/$1x$1.png  [L,NC]

## Check if the request has 2 parameters
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !storage                    [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    -f
RewriteRule ^images/([^x]+)x([^/]+)/?  /storage/$1/$1x$2.png  [L,NC]

## Else, map to failed.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !storage                     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !failed\.php                 [NC]
RewriteRule .*   /somedir/failed.php                     [L]
```

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: @CodeProtocol No, that wont work because the OR can only be used in conditions. If I understood right, when there is only one parameter in the incoming URL it has to be used for both Height and Width, right? If so, you will need another rule and I can update my answer with that option. Please confirm.

Comment: yes please If only `images` then `storage/200/200x200.png`. If `images/250` then `storage/250/250x250.png` if `images/250x120` then `storage/250/250x120.png`.

Comment: When there is no parameter in the incoming URL, is it always `200`?

Comment: The problem is conditions only work for the next rule and all are needed for each one. On the other hand, the parameters can't be optional as the substitution URL is different in each case, so there is no way, that I know, to make that code shorter.

Comment: Updated with a version that saves 3 lines in the whole rule-set. That's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how your .htaccess is currently setup, you could route all non existing files to failed.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /failed.php [L]
```